# Recursive method call that uses reflection fails due to abstract class in hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, reflection, abstract-class

I have simplified the issue I'm facing in the SSCCE at the bottom.

As it is the output is `B C D` as one would expect.
If I make, say, `C` abstract then `D` gets printed and after that an exception occurs:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at A.recursiveCall(A.java:22)
    at A.entryPoint(A.java:10)
    at A.main(A.java:6)
```

Since some of the classes in the hierarchy will necessarily be abstract then my code breaks.

The only solution I can come up with is to remove the `recursiveCall` method and make `classSpecificMethod` call the parent implementation.

To avoid the redundancy and possibility for error that this introduces I think (I've never used it) I could use AspectJ to generate the code at compile time. But it seems overkill to me. At least for now since I don't have other uses for it.

If there aren't other ways to do this in plain Java I also welcome answers that use other JVM languages and tools.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

abstract class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new D().entryPoint();
    }

    void entryPoint() {
        System.out.println(recursiveCall());
    }

    private String recursiveCall() {
        String result = "";
        Class<?> parentClass = getClass().getSuperclass();
        if (parentClass != A.class) {
            try {
                Constructor<?> baseConstructor = parentClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
                baseConstructor.setAccessible(true);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                A baseInstance = (A) baseConstructor.newInstance();
                result = baseInstance.recursiveCall() + " ";
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        result += classSpecificMethod();
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract String classSpecificMethod();

    static class B extends A {
        protected String classSpecificMethod() { return "B"; }
    }

    static class C extends B {
        protected String classSpecificMethod() { return "C"; }
    }

    static class D extends C {
        protected String classSpecificMethod() { return "D"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  I can literally see in the code where you're trying to instantiate an object of `A` in `recursiveCall`, but Java doesn't allow you to do that for `abstract` classes (that's the entire point of making a class `abstract`).

Comment: The code above works fine, the instantiation is inside the `if (parentClass != A.class)` block

Comment: The code I was referring to is this line: `A baseInstance = (A) baseConstructor.newInstance();` which tosses an `InstantiationException` just like it's supposed to because you're trying to instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: I see. I thought you were saying that the issue is that `A` is abstract and hence that it shouldn't be so.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an instance of an abstract class.
The only way I see to solve this is by making the recursiveCall() skip abstract classes:

```
private String recursiveCall() {
    String result = "";
    Class<?> parentClass=getClass();
    do {
        parentClass = parentClass.getSuperclass();
    } while (Modifier.isAbstract(parentClass.getModifiers()) && parentClass != A.class);
    if (parentClass != A.class) {
        try {
            Constructor<?> baseConstructor = parentClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
            baseConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            A baseInstance = (A) baseConstructor.newInstance();
            result = baseInstance.recursiveCall() + " ";
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    result += classSpecificMethod();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea but unfortunately I need to call `classSpecificMethod` on abstract classes too.